# EditText in (Dialog)Fragment

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-dialogfragment

I am right now learning about Fragments and followed an example at Android Devoloper where a timepicker-dialog is created using a static class. The overridden method onCreateDialog(Bundle SavedInstanceState) returns a Dialog.

Now I want to do the same but substitute the TimePicker with a simple EditText. I do not know how to change this static class to accomplish this? Could I for instance still return a Dialog when using an EditText instead? What Callback-method should be used?

Here follows the static class that handles the TimePicker in a DialogFragment. I just - as mentioned change it to a Fragment inplementing Edittext.

Thank you!!!

```
 public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            }
}
```

Comment: Create your own class that will extend Dialog class and inside this class you will need to override some methods of Dialog class like setContentView() that will require View object where you can add your EditText controll.

Comment: Could You be more specific in what exactly you're trying to achieve? Have You tried http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout ?